# parse data between controller and partialview

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Hi i want to parse data to my partial view from controller. I get data from database and convert it into List and said list string want to send to partial view so i could do stuff with it ...

```
    public ActionResult ManipulateData()
    {
        List<string> str = new List<string>();
        DataTable data = LoadDBData();

        foreach (DataRow row in data.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataColumn Col in data.Columns)
            {
                str.Add(row[Col].ToString());
            }
        }
        return View(str);
    }
```

this is the code that i have been trying out and now how to acces the str data inside a partial view?

(second idea was to return List with function and somehow call a function and pass data to variable inside view)

Comment: Is the problem that you don't know how to use the model in the view or something else? This seems to be pretty basic MVC stuff at a glance so I'm just wanting to check in case I end up being patronising. :)

Comment: @Chris you big ole meany.

Comment: well i am not sure how to declare @ .... model so i can use it in foreach loop ... i am aware that this is basics but i couldn't find anything. I don't have model for that , it's a basic type - and i don't know how to send up basic type to view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass data from view to view as far as you want.

Say you have this view:

```
@model IEnumerable<DataLayer.StructuresList_Result>
<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

@{
    Html.RenderPartial("_StructureList", Model);
}
```

As you can see, I have a main view with a model and I'm passing that model directly to the partial view.

You can also create wrappers for your model.

```
public class Wrapper
{
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public IEnumerable<MyClass> SubClasses {get;set;}
}

public class SubClass
{
  //your subclass code here
}
```

Then pass this wrapper to your model in the traditional way:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  //get my wrapper object
  Warpper w = new Wrapper();
  return View(w);
{
```

And then use it in your parent view and pass the SubClass to the partial:

```
@model YourProjectName.Wrapper
<h2>Model.Name</h2>

@{
   Html.RenderPartial("_StructureList", Model.SubClasses);
}
```

Which then you can access that data the same way you access data in your parent view.

```
@model IEnumerable<string>
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
 //do something with model data
}
```

I didn't test any of this but it looks right.

---

Chris is right about one thing, this is pretty basic asp.net MVC stuff here.  I suggest you read some MVC tutorials:

ASP.NET site: http://www.asp.net/mvc

Youtube Videos: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-pzwRwYlXMw&list=PL6n9fhu94yhVm6S8I2xd6nYz2ZORd7X2v

Comment: so there is no way to call a function that returns some value inside view ? for example @{ var = controller,function } ? later i'll have many different data inside main view so i'll be problematic to make one model containing all information to send to partial views

Comment: hmmm i can try to do it with ViewData ... but it's probably not the most elegant way

Comment: You can call controller actions with a javascript ajax call, if that's what you want to do.  However, if it's data that can be processed in the controller before passing to your view, then you should process everything and package it all up in a model, and pass it to your parent view then disseminate it to your partials.  The only exception, for me, is if you need data dynamically processed from user input - then I would use an ajax call.

Comment: If you want to effectively run more stuff from the controller then instead of rendering the partials directly you can call child Actions that can take parameters, do whatever you want with them and then pass whatever model you want (whether that is a user model or standard classes such as List<T>). This would be done with something like `@Html.Action("MyActionName", "MyControllerName", new { Parameter1 = "foo"})`. This would call an action called `MyActionName` on controller `MyControllerName` with one parameter as given.

Comment: The main advantage of this technique is that it can keep your view models a bit more compact. You can have just an id on the main model and then have a child action that would take that id, run it through a factory and then pass it on to the appropriate view.